# Where to put and how to load local text file in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm a bit confused. I have already created my database and tables. I have a txt file on my desktop that contains data I would like to import.

In my database I have two tables

People & registration.

The people table contains a unique person id with their name and email.
The registration table contains a country, date, and registered id for each person. They can have multiples.

The text files I was given looks like this:

```
Email,Full Name,Country,Date Registered
Carley_Bahringer@example.com,Carley Bahringer,Papua New Guinea,1987-10-03 22:09:54 
Patricia_Fadel@example.com,Patricia Fadel,Saint Lucia,2012-05-10 11:07:49 
Sedrick@example.com,Sedrick Kuphal,Chile,2007-11-12 00:09:53 
Briana_Berge@example.com,Briana Berge,Nicaragua,2006-03-26 15:32:08 
Lucy_Lockman@example.com,Lucy Lockman,Iceland,2014-02-13 10:26:57 
Lucy_Lockman@example.com,Lucy Lockman,Germany,1999-02-12 00:14:54 
Ayden_Flatley@example.com,Ayden Flatley,France,1987-01-23 21:43:22 
Alec.Boyle@example.com,Alec Boyle,Brazil,2007-08-23 13:42:41 
Ozella_Feil@example.com,Ozella Feil,Lesotho,2005-12-30 18:24:59 
Ozella_Feil@example.com,Ozella Feil,Sweden,2009-06-19 10:32:55
```

How do I import this data into my database/tables?

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/import-csv-file-mysql-table/ The text file is stored on the client side, since the `LOAD` commands are client side extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LOAD DATA function of mysql  like this:

```
#table structure: example

col-2 col-1 col-3

In this case we need to specify column-name sequence of csv file in order to get data loaded in to proper columns.

LOAD DATA INFILE ‘path/to/example.csv’ INTO TABLE example FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘,’ LINES TERMINATED BY ‘\n’ IGNORE 1 LINES (col-1,col-2,col-3);
```

You can run two such queries both for people & registration table separately.